# How does Azure WorkerRole handle its OS page file?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, pagefile

The Azure WorkerRole offers the possibility to create [LocalStorage resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/gg557552.aspx). My understanding is that the OS page file is going to use the local storage space. However, as it's possible to create multiple local storage spaces, it's not clear to me which one is going to be used by the OS for the pagefile. Could someone shed light on how the pagefile works out in the case of an Azure WorkerRole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pagefile remains on the Role's system disk which you don't have direct access to.

LocalStorage is created on a temporary disk attached to the host when running.

You could theoretically script the moving of the pagefile to the LocalStorage drive but you'd be unlikely to be successful as the LocalStorage drive can be different depending on the host.

Comment: Any idea about the capacity of this temporary disk? Is it documented anywhere? Thanks!

Comment: To be clear also - when I say "different depending on the host" I mean the drive letter can change so the path may not always be the same. For capacity see "Local resource" in "Disk Sizes" columns in the section titled "Sizes for Web and Worker Roles" on this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn197896.aspx. Bottom line is it capacity varies depending on the size of the role you provision.